# Discord bot using discord.py command not working.PLZ

Tags: bots, discord.py

I just start learning how to write my own bot in discord.py. However, I followed the tutorial on Youtube, using exactly the same code but it doesn't work on my server.

```
import discord from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello there.')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member}has joined the server!!')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'Seeya,{member}. Oh wait\n can we?')



client.run('NzU1MjI2Mzk1MjM5Nzc2Mjg2.XGGNZA.s2qLVQMONMLqs1f8Zky9wtM6ZDo')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the default provided `on_message` forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `client.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello there.')
    
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

[Why does on_message make my commands stop working?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)